# *Update: How to parse html with python/ beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

First, I'm pretty new to Python. I'm trying to scrape contact information from offline websites and output the info to a csv. I'd like to grab the page url(not sure how to do this from the html), email, phone, location data if possible, any names, any phone numbers and the tag line for the html site if it exists.

---

Updated #2 code:

```
import os, csv, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

topdir = 'C:\\projects\\training\\html'
output = csv.writer(open("scrape.csv", "wb+"))
output.writerow(["headline", "name", "email", "phone", "location", "url"])
all_contacts = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir):
    for f in files:
        if f.lower().endswith((".html", ".htm")):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

            def mailto_link(soup):          
            if soup.name != 'a':
                return None
            for key, value in soup.attrs:
                if key == 'href':
                    m = re.search('mailto:(.*)',value)
                if m:
                    all_contacts.append(m)
                return m.group(1)
            return None

            for ul in soup.findAll('ul'):
            contact = []
            for li in soup.findAll('li'):
                s = li.find('span')
                if not (s and s.string):
                    continue
                if s.string == 'Email:':
                    a = li.find(mailto_link)
                    if a:
                    contact['email'] = mailto_link(a)
                elif s.string == 'Website:':
                    a = li.find('a')
                    if a:
                    contact['website'] = a['href']
                elif s.string == 'Phone:':
                    contact['phone'] = unicode(s.nextSibling).strip()
            all_contacts.append(contact)
            output.writerow([all_contacts])

print "Finished"
```

This output currently doesn't return anything other than the row headers. What am I missing here? This should be at least returning some info from the html file, which is this page: http://bendoeslife.tumblr.com/about

Comment: You usually _can't_ get the page URL from the page HTML; you need to save this at fetch time. As for the rest… we need to see some sample data to tell you what's wrong with your parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two problems here.

First, `f` is a filename, not the file contents, or the Soup made from those contents. So, `f.find('h2')` is going to find `'h2'` within the filename, which isn't very useful.

Second, most `find` methods (including `str.find`, which is what you're calling) return an index, not a substring. Calling `str` on that index is just going to give you the string version of a number. For example:

```
>>> s = 'A string with an h2 in it'
>>> i = s.find('h2')
>>> str(i)
'17'
```

So, your code is doing something like this:

```
>>> f = 'C:\\python\\training\\offline\\somehtml.html'
>>> headline = f.find('h2')
>>> str(headline)
'-1'
```

You probably want to call methods on the `soup` object, rather than `f`. `BeautifulSoup.find` returns a "sub-tree" of the soup, which is exactly what you want to stringify here.

However, it's impossible to test that without your sample input, so I can't promise that's the only problem in your code.

Meanwhile, when you get stuck with something like this, you should try printing out intermediate values. Print out `f`, and `headline`, and `headline2`, and it will be much more obvious why `headline3` is wrong.

---

Just replacing the `f` with `soup` in the `find` calls, and fixing your indentation error, running against your sample file http://bendoeslife.tumblr.com/about now works.

It doesn't do anything all that useful, however. Since there's no `h2` tag anywhere in the file, `headline` ends up as `None`. And the same goes for most of the other fields. The only thing that *does* find anything is `url`, because you're asking it to find an empty string, which will find *something* arbitrary. With three different parsers, I get `<p>about</p>` or `<html><body><p>about</p></body></html>`, and `<html><body></body></html>`…

You need to actually understand the structure of the file you're trying to parse before you can do anything useful with it. In this case, for example, there is an email address, but it's in an `<a>` element with a title of `"Email"`, with an `<li>` element with an `id` of `"email"`. So, you need to write a find to locate it based on one of those criteria, or something else it actually matches.